# How to transfer a subscription to another function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a UserService function, I subscribe to it. If there are no errors, I take the data and want to return it with the possibility of another function to subscribe to it.
I already had a similar question, but there were two nested functions, there the issue was solved using switchMap. But how can it be used here?
so that you can write like this:

```
this.authService.getUser(1).subscribe(...
```

But this code gives an error, I myself understand that this is wrong, but I don't understand how to use switchMap or map here:

```
export class AuthService {
getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {  
  this.httpService.getUser(id).subscribe(
    (resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
      if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
        return resultService.data;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
}
}
    
export interface User{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you should avoid to subscribe inside the function, you should return the observable instead in order to subscribe to the function:

```
export class AuthService {
  getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {  
    return this.httpService.getUser(id).pipe(
      map((resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
        if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
          return resultService.data;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and if you want you can make you code much shorter:

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {  
  return this.httpService.getUser(id).pipe(
    map((res: DataResponse<User>) => res.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL ? res.data : null)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve that you have to return the `Observable` itself from the `getUser` function, instead of `subscribe` within it.

You can try something like the following:

```js
// import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {
  return this.httpService.getUser(id).pipe(
    map((resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
      if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
        return resultService.data;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

The [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator is used here to transform the result of the `this.httpService.getUser` to the preferred type.

Then you can `subscribe` to it within the other components when you need it only:

```
this.authService.getUser(1).subscribe(...)
```